# Timestamps for log events are 10 minutes off

Tags: c#, timestamp, etw, slab

I recently started using ETW with [SLAB](http://slab.codeplex.com/) and noticed that time stamps for events are a bit off. Is there any reason that time stamps outputted from `EventSource.WriteEvent` would be 10 minutes earlier than when the event actually occurred? This is not a big deal, but I am curious why this might be happening.

Example Code:

```
[Event(100, Level = EventLevel.Informational)]
public void Info(string message)
{
       if (this.IsEnabled())
       {
           this.WriteEvent(100, message);
       }
}
```

The output might look like this:

```
EventId : 100, Level : Informational, Message : Method DocumentODSRepository.GetDocuments entered., Payload : [methodName : DocumentODSRepository.GetDocuments] , EventName : MethodEnteredInfo, Timestamp : 2014-06-25T20:38:18.8503447Z
```

However, the Timestamp should be 2014-06-25T20:48:18.8503447Z.

Comment: capture the events with PerfView (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2012/07/09/logging-your-own-etw-events-in-c-system-diagnostics-tracing-eventsource.aspx). Do you also see the wrongs time in the generated ETL file?

Comment: have you tried this? Does WPA/xperfview also show the wrong timestamp of the event after opening the ETL file?

Comment: Did you end up solving this? I have an ETL file with CreateTimes which are about 15 minutes earlier than when the events actually happened...

Comment: @Dina, no, sadly I didn't find a solution to this issue. Unfortunately, I no longer with with ETW and SLAB on a daily basis.